# ionic framework iOS input focus issues

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am currently having trouble with focus on my inputs for iOS. It works perfectly on Android, but for some reason something is going with iOS where sometimes it takes multiple clicks before it actually registers a click event on the input and opens the keyboard with focus in the input and other times it gives focus to some random element behind the visible one so the keyboard opens, but the input field doesn't have focus. We have multiple inputs that are hidden behind the visible one, but I don't think that should matter.

Ionic info:
Your system information:
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.1
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X Sierra
Node Version: v6.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a

A basic outline of our code can be found here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzYEQk

```
<ion-view title="COMPANY" hide-back-button="true" can-swipe-back="false">
  <ion-content class="background-cntr" delegate-handle="mainScroll">
    SOME HTML CONTENT
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer-bar>
    <div class="list">
          <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <input type="text"/>
                    <input type="text" style="display:none;"/>
        </label>
        <button>Test</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment above, but for anyone that got excited about - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617967-keyboarddisplayrequiresuseractio - that appears to now be deprecated for anything above iOS 12 webview/devices. Apple is purposefully stopping this action from being possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution and to make it work better. Instead of having all the inputs within the footer, I add and remove them every time. That way there is only ever one input within the footer. This seems to work fairly well. The second thing I did was to handle the phantom keyboard case by add the following code to the controller.

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function(){
  if (document.activeElement.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
    var activeElement = document.querySelector("#chat_footer_inputs input");
    if (activeElement) {
      activeElement.focus();
      $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(true);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember adding this preference tag on my `config.xml` file before.

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

This made the autofocus work before.

Comment: this saved my day!!!! I discover it trying to open pragmatically keyboard: the plugin itself say you to add that row to your config.xml

Comment: [Pat Vee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4114403) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482066) saying "..for anyone that got excited about - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617967-keyboarddisplayrequiresuseractio - that appears to now be deprecated for anything above iOS 12 webview/devices.  Apple is purposefully stopping this action from being possible."

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.factory('focus', function($timeout, $window) {
        return function(id) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var element =     $window.document.getElementById(id);
                if(element)
                    element.focus();
            });
        };
    })
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, focus) {
 focus("myInput")

});
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Input trouble on iOS</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ion-view title="COMPANY" hide-back-button="true" can-swipe-back="false">
      <ion-content class="background-cntr" delegate-handle="mainScroll">
        SOME HTML CONTENT
      </ion-content>
      <ion-footer-bar>
        <div class="list">
              <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
              <input type="text"/>
                        <input type="text" style="display:none;"/>
            </label>
            <button>Test</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-footer-bar>
    </ion-view>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would work, but I need the user to initiate the focus rather than the js. So it would be on tap/clcik.